# Android EditText duplicates every character I type

Tags: android, gridview, input, android-edittext, listadapter

I have several rows of EditText objects, which are maintained by my custom BaseAdapter class.

The EditText objects should only be able to accept numbers. In the image shown, I typed in "12345". As you can see, everything I type gets immediately duplicated.

I've found that the problem goes away if I remove the line of code that filters the EditText for numbers:

`et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);`

Any idea what's going on?

I'm using a TextWatcher to listen for the input, which you can see in the getView() method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.number, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();              
                holder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number_edittext);
                holder.editText = setEditTextFilters(holder.editText);
                holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {                      
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2){}
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        textBoxStrings[holder.row] = s.toString(); 
                        System.out.println("row: " + holder.row + " " + s.toString());
                    }
                });

                convertView.setTag(holder); 
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.row = position;
            holder.editText.setText(textBoxStrings[holder.row]);

            TextView rowtext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number_rowtext);
            rowtext.setText("Row " + holder.row);
            return convertView;
}
```

Filters are added to the EditText using the following method:

```
public EditText setEditTextFilters(EditText et) {           
        int maxLength = numColsMEM;
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
        et.setFilters(FilterArray);
        et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        et.setSingleLine();
        return et;
}
```

[image: What I see after entering the numbers "12345"]

Comment: just a blind suggestion: have your tried using "android:phone" in the XML layout, instead of programmatically setting it?

Comment: This activity handles several possibilities. If I'm in another game mode, then characters would be allowed, so I have to set the properties programatically.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that the problem may be that your textChangedListener shouldn't be setting the textBoxStrings[holder.row] because the default textChangedListener is probably already doing this.

Comment: not sure what you mean by default textChangedListener. Another quirk is that the text is only duplicated if I press the key of an actual number. In phone input mode, if I use a letter, the proper number displays and there is only one of it.

Answer (score 0):

Was an issue with the emulator, doesn't occur on a true device. One of those things.